# Toggling True and False in Redux State via a Checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Total React/Redux noob here; In my app I have a form checkbox that should set an option to true or false in my state.

Here's my checkbox - I'm not sure how to set this true/false flag correctly:

```
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  onChange={ (e) => this.props.dispatch(setOption({'currentAddress': [true/false flag]})) }
  defaultChecked={ true }
/>
```

The Action - this should be reusable by other checkboxes on the form:

```
const SET_OPTION = 'SET_OPTION';

export const setOption = (option) => ({
    type: SET_OPTION,
    payload: option
})
```

And the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  formOptions {
    currentAddress: true,
    isEmployed: true,
    // ...
  }
}

const Reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_OPTION:
      let option = action.payload
      return { ...state.formOptions, option};
    default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

My questions are:

- How do I toggle the option between true and false in my state?
- How can I reference this option later in my code? Is `getState()` the standard way?

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

If the initial state of your store is

```
{
  formOptions: {
    currentAddress: true,
    isEmployed: true
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then in the reducer don't return

```
{
  ...state.formOptions
}
```

Because this will return a state which looks different to the initial structure

```
{
  currentAddress: true,
  isEmployed: true
  // ...
}
```

Read here about the spread operator behaviour: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Instead your reducer should look like

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_OPTION:
      return {
        ...state, // copy data in state other than formOptions
        formOptions: {
          ...state.formOptions, // copy other formOptions
          ...action.payload // here you are overwriting the 'currentAddress' property since action.payload = { 'currentAddress': true/false }
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Reducer is just a function which takes `state` and return new `state` :)

2)

You probably would like to bind the Redux store with a React component to be able to pass the Redux data in React component props. Full instructions are available here: https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react